# Add column to DataFrame in sparkR

Tags: r, sparkr

I would like to add a column filled with a character `N` in a DataFrame in SparkR. I would do it like that with non-SparkR code :

```
df$new_column <- "N"
```

But with SparkR, I get the following error :

```
Error: class(value) == "Column" || is.null(value) is not TRUE
```

I've tried insane things to manage it, I was able to create a column using another (existing) one with `df <- withColumn(df, "new_column", df$existing_column)`, but this simple thing, nope...

Any help ?

Thanks.

Comment: The only hack I know for this is to use `ifelse` with the same return value for both conditions. So `df$new <- ifelse(condition, 'N', 'N')`.

Comment: Worked, thank you very much (put it as an answer if you want me to validate it)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The straight solution will be to use `SparkR::lit()` function:

```
df_new = withColumn(df, "new_column_name", lit("N"))
```

---

### Edit 7/17/2019

In newer Spark versions, the following also works:

```
df1$new_column <- "N"
df1[["new_column"]] <- "N"
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about `lit()`, will delete my answer when the OP accepts yours.

Comment: How would I add a column full of NAs ?

Comment: When I attempt to do the same task, `df <- withColumn(df, "col", lit(NA))`, and then return`str(df)`, I receive the following error: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Unsupported data type:  null`. I can open a new question, but thought that @DmitriySelivanov or @fmalaussena may know the answer after working with the problem.

Comment: `df <- withColumn(df, "col", lit("NA"))` should work (with `" "` around the `NA`)

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to use `SparkR::lit()` that more closely mimics the syntax you tried first:

```
df$new_column <- lit("N")
```