# SparkR data frame add column with constant value

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I want to do this in a sparkR data frame:

I'm adding a column with the String "a" to the data frame

```
df$new_col <- "a"
```

I can't find a way to do this in sparkR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in an older post [Add column to DataFrame in sparkR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327652/add-column-to-dataframe-in-sparkr)

```
df$new <- ifelse(condition, "N", "N")
```

Comment: I found a better solution : `df$new <- lit( "N")`